# Wishlist in ecommerce website?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, web, local-storage, e-commerce

I'm creating a wishlist for an ecommerce website. I couldn't find a good article on this.

I need to create a wishlist that works for both a **logged in** user or **guest** user ( *not logged in*).
So I did some analysis and have decided to use browser **local storage** for saving wish list items and sync them with the database when user logs in.

The technology in the current website is **C# ASP.Net MVC** and **Jquery** at client side.

My query is:

- Is there any alternative way to achieve this ?

Comment: I've shortened the question , can you unhold it now ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach might be the simplest one, but if you have time a more robust solution might be using the DB for anonymous users as well.

**Alternative:** You could use anonymous data in MVC to identify a browser session that is not logged in: http://www.toplinestrategies.com/blogs/net/anonymous-identification-mvc
Then you could have a WishList table that stores WishItems and UserId for logged in user and AnonymousId those not logged in.

Comment: Thanks thats a different way to look at it, but I mainly wanted to avoid calling the server to store wishlist items